# PySide2: "MouseReleaseEvernt" not triggered in QGraphicsItem

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I have a custom QGraphicsItem on a QgraphicsScene. And I'm trying to draw on QGraphicsItem following mouse events. Here is what I implemented:

The custom QGraphicsItem in implemented in `GraphicsItem_custom.py`

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem
from PySide2.QtCore import QPointF, QRectF, Qt, QRect, QPoint
from PySide2.QtGui import QPen, QPainter, QPixmap


class GraphicsItem_custom(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.start, self.end = QPoint(), QPoint()
        self.rectangles = []

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, 500, 300)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 6, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawText(QPointF(0, 10), "Hiya")
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

        for rectangle in self.rectangles:
            painter.drawRect(rectangle)

        if not self.start.isNull() and not self.end.isNull() and self.start != self.end:
            rect = QRect(self.start, self.end)
            print("paintEvent start: " + str(self.start) + ", end: " + str(self.end))
            print("")
            painter.drawRect(rect.normalized())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        print("Pressed")
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start = event.pos()
            self.end = self.start
            self.update()
            print("left button")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("Move")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        print("Released")
        if event.button() and Qt.LeftButton:

            if self.start != self.end:
                r = QRect(self.start, self.end).normalized()
                self.rectangles.append(r)
                self.start = self.end = QPoint()

            self.update()
```

Then, in `main.py` I create the scene and view, and add the item onto the scene:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setGeometry(0,0,1000, 700)
        self.item = GraphicsItem_custom()
        self.scene.addItem(self.item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # don't auto scale when drag app to a different monitor.
    # QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QWidget {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    ''')

    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

When I run this code, the mousePressEvent() is triggered when I press, however, mouseReleaseEvent() is not when triggered when I release. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`mousePressEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent) explains:

> If you do reimplement this function, event will by default be accepted (see QEvent::accept()), and this item is then the mouse grabber. This allows the item to receive future move, release and doubleclick events.

If you call the base implementation like this:

```
super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

the result will the same as *not reimplementing* the function (you're calling the default behavior), so the event will *not* accepted, meaning that the item will not receive move, release and doubleclick events, unless you've set specific flags that trigger those event handlers due to their nature (like `Qt.ItemIsMovable`).

You have to carefully decide if you actually need to call the base implementation or not (usually depending on the flags), and eventually add this at some point in the `mousePressEvent()` override:

```
event.setAccepted(True)
```